# garbage collection of class instances containing static members

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection

I'm a bit confused about Java garbage collecting of class instances containing static members:

Some posts say the types containg static references will not be collected, others say it will be.

I need a certain class instances (say class AA) to share a reference to another type (it is a SQL DataSource): The DS gets created when AA static class member is accessed the first time,while the AA instances uses this shared DS inside their methods to get a connection. The questions are:

1. will the static DS prevent AA instances to be garbage collected?
2. if i put AA instances to null and it gets garbage collected, will the DS be gc too?
3. Getting the connection from this static DS inside AA moethods is thread safe?

In my opinion static DS should not be garbage collected, since its a class member not an instance member, while AA instances should be collected. Anyway I'd like to have the opinion of more experienced java programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The static reference will not prevent AA instances to be garbage collected.
2. The static data source will only be garbage collected if it is not referenced anymore. E.g. after setting AA.DS = null the original data source can be collected.
   Removing the references to all AA instances will not help, since the static DS reference still holds.
3. It depends on how you code it. This is not thread safe by design.

Comment: thank you for your answer , about point 3 : this is an old web application i'm porting, trying to change as less as possibile. DS gets called in a method named "openConnection" and just assigns the getconnection returned reference to a (non static) instance member of AA . When a servlet or jsp needs to use AA it creates a new instance, is this mechanism thread safe ? i fear not since global servlet (jsp) members are not thread safe

Comment: Probably the data source takes care of concurrent calls, but you need to verify this for the specific implementation you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Objects referenced by static fields only become eligible if the class as a whole is eligible for GC, which can only happen when **all** of the following are true:

- no instances of that class exist
- all other classes loaded by its `ClassLoader` are eligible for GC
- no references to its `Class` object exist.

In a common web application, for example, classes will not be unloaded while the web app is loaded, but should be unloaded when the web app is removed from the server (although memory leaks are not unknown in this case).